# Magento2 - Is it possible to get base url in a static block?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, static-block, cms-block, magento-2.1.2

I'm trying to get the base url in a static block.

I've tried the following code:

```
<a href="{{base url=""}}../business">
```

I knew this wasn't going to work because it needs `<?php ?>` around it. 
Is there an alternative way to get the base url in a static block through the backend?

Screenshot for clarification:
[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can get base url in static block like this.

```
<a href="{{store direct_url="business"}}">Your link</a>
```

Comment: Using URL routing like this is always preferred over concatenating the URL.

Answer (score 2):

You can get it by `{{config path="web/unsecure/base_url"}}` and If you want to append another URL then you can do like

`<a href="{{config path="web/unsecure/base_url"}}test213/32"> test </a>`

If you want secure base URL then you can get it by

`{{config path="web/secure/base_url"}}`

Answer (score 0):

You can add store URL in static block:

```
<a href="{{store direct_url='identifier'}}">Your link</a>
```